# Einstein's frozen wave?

Tags: special-relativity, waves, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

Here's the quote from Stephen Hawking's latest book.

> At the age of sixteen, when he (Einstein) visualised riding on a beam of light, he realised that from this vantage light would appear as a frozen wave. That image ultimately led to the theory of special relativity.

What does "frozen wave" mean?

Comment: Hi Harry, sorry for butchering your question a bit. But the part about the grammatical correctness of the sentence is quite off-topic. For what it's worth, I don't believe there's a comma missing. I am not a native speaker though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we consider a plane wave:

$$ y(t,x) = A\sin(\omega t - kx + \phi) \tag{1} $$

The velocity of the wave is:

$$ v = \frac{\omega}{k} $$

If you are moving at the same velocity as the wave your position is given by:

$$ x = vt = \frac{\omega}{k} t $$

The value of the wave at your position is given by substituting your position into the value for $x$ in equation (1), and if we do this we get:

$$ y(t,x) = A\sin(\omega t - k \frac{\omega}{k} t + \phi) = A\sin(\phi) $$

So to you the wave just has the constant value $A\sin(\phi)$ and doesn't change with time. This is what Hawking means by the wave being *frozen*.